# Connecting to IRC via a proxy (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, proxy, irc

I wish to hide my IP when connecting to IRC via my .NET app. I currently use the IrcDotNet library but it doesn't seems to support proxies.

I've not had much experience with sockets, so I think modifying IrcDotNet would be easier than making my own IRC library.  I looked around for socket libraries that handle proxy connections that I could implement in IrcDotNet.  I found one called ProxySocket but it only supports BeginConnect not the new ASyncConnect method that IrcDotNet uses.

To break it down, in order of preference, here's what I'm looking for;

1. An IRC library that supports connecting via a HTTP/SOCKS proxy
2. A socket library that supports connecting via a HTTP/SOCKS proxy via
   ASyncConnect
3. Example code on how to extend the socket class to support connecting
   via a HTTP/SOCKS proxy via ASyncConnect

The version of IrcDotNet I am using is 0.4.1 found at https://launchpad.net/ircdotnet.

Update 1: Still no luck i'm afraid.  Fredrik92's answer, while helpful, is not applicable to the version of IrcDotNet I am using (see above).

Comment: +1 for well phrased question. Just out of interest, what are you using the .NET IRC client for?

Answer (score 0):

The IRC.NET library uses the standard Socket class in the System.Net.Sockets namespace.

So you could just modify the *IrcDotNet/IrcClient.cs* file in the IRC.NET source code (@ http://ircdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

You should add a constructor for proxy enabled IRC clients and call the default constructor.

Then all you should need to do is to modify the Connect methods in the same file (almost at the bottom). Each time they call `this.client.BeginConnect(..)` you have to add code for connecting to the Proxy (instead of the remote host)

Now you only have to create a new Connect-callback method that sends a HTTP CONNECT request to the proxy. Read the response from the HTTP Proxy and then everything else should work.

In this case I would write the HTTP request as raw ASCII bytes to the Proxy (instead of using the HttpWebRequest class), so that you have full control over the network stream you get in return...

You should add sth. like this to the IrcClient class:

```
private bool useProxy = false;
private IWebProxy proxy;
private IEnumerable<Uri> proxyRemoteUris;

public IrcClient(IWebProxy proxy)
    : this()
{
   this.useProxy = true;
   this.proxy = proxy;
}

private void ProxyPerformHttpConnect(Uri remoteIrcUri)
{
  string httpConnectRequest = string.Format("CONNECT {0}:{1} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {2}\r\n\r\n",
    remoteIrcUri.Host, remoteIrcUri.Port, this.proxy.GetProxy(remoteIrcUri));
  byte[] httpConnectData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(httpConnectRequest);

  this.stream.Write(httpConnectData, 0, httpConnectData.Length);

  bool responseReady = false;
  string responseText = string.Empty;
  // Byte-by-byte reading required, because StringReader will read more than just the HTTP response header
  do
  {
    int readByte = this.stream.ReadByte();
    if (readByte < 0)
      throw new WebException(message: null, status: WebExceptionStatus.ConnectionClosed);

    char readChar = (char)(readByte); // Only works because HTTP Headers are ASCII encoded.
    responseText += readChar;

    responseReady = responseText.EndsWith("\r\n\r\n");
  } while (!responseReady);

  int statusStart = responseText.IndexOf(' ') + 1;
  int reasonStart = responseText.IndexOf(' ', statusStart) + 1;
  int reasonEnd = responseText.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '\r', '\n'});
  HttpStatusCode responseStatus = (HttpStatusCode)(int.Parse(responseText.Substring(responseText.IndexOf(' ') + 1, length: 3)));
  if (responseStatus != HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    string reasonText = responseText.Substring(reasonStart, reasonEnd - reasonStart);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reasonText))
      reasonText = null;
    throw new WebException(reasonText, WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure);
  }

  // Finished Response Header read...
}

private void ProxyConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  try
  {
    this.client.EndConnect(ar);
    this.stream = this.client.GetStream();

    bool proxyTunnelEstablished = false;
    WebException lastWebException = null;
    foreach (Uri remoteIrcUri in this.proxyRemoteUris)
    {
      if (this.client.Connected == false)
      {
        // Re-establish connection with proxy...
        Uri proxyUri = this.proxy.GetProxy(remoteIrcUri);
        this.client.Connect(proxyUri.Host, proxyUri.Port);
      }

      try
      {
        ProxyPerformHttpConnect(remoteIrcUri);
        proxyTunnelEstablished = true;
        break;
      }
      catch (WebException webExcept)
      {
        lastWebException = webExcept;                        
      }
    }

    if (!proxyTunnelEstablished)
    {
      OnConnectFailed(new IrcErrorEventArgs(lastWebException));
      return;
    }

    this.writer = new StreamWriter(this.stream, Encoding.Default);
    this.reader = new StreamReader(this.stream, Encoding.Default);

    HandleClientConnected((IrcRegistrationInfo)ar.AsyncState);
    this.readThread.Start();
    this.writeThread.Start();

    OnConnected(new EventArgs());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    OnConnectFailed(new IrcErrorEventArgs(ex));
  }
}
```

The code for the proxy handling in all Connect methods of the `IrcClient` class would thus look sth. like this:

```
// Code snippet to insert before the call to this.client.BeginConnect(...)
if (this.useProxy)
{
  // Assign host and port variables for EndPoint objects:
  // var host = remoteEP.Address;
  // var port = remoteEP.Port;
  this.proxyRemoteUris = new Uri[] { new Uri(string.Format("irc://{0}:{1}/", host, port)) };
  // Replace the line above with the following line in the method where an array of IP addresses is specified as a parameter
  // this.proxyRemoteUris = from ip in addresses select new Uri(string.Format("irc://{0}:{1}/", ip, port));
  Uri proxyUri = this.proxy.GetProxy(this.proxyRemoteUris.First());
  string proxyHost = proxyUri.Host;
  int proxyPort = proxyUri.Port;
  this.client.BeginConnect(proxyHost, proxyPort, ProxyConnectCallback, registrationInfo);
}
else
  // Original this.client.BeginConnect(...) call here...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was very detailed and would be exactly what I needed.  The problem is the code you looked at is from a much older version released in 2010.  The latest version is hosted at https://launchpad.net/ircdotnet.  It no longer uses BeginConnect, but ASyncConnect.  I have a library I could use for BeginConnect, but I've no idea what I'm doing with ASyncConnect.

Comment: Then it will be a lot more difficult... There's a lot of code conversion you need to do... But this is actually not because of the ConnectAsync calls, but because they use Sockets instead of the TcpClient class... Strange...